# How to scale on x-axis with Core Plot

Tags: iphone, scale, core-plot

I have a barchart display the smoking counter, day by day. Each column
represents one day. I would like to view the data on week, month,
year, on the same graph by drag on the X-Axis. If I drag the x-axis to
the right, the value on the x-axis come from month to day (smaller
value scale). If I drag the x-axis to the left, the value on the x-
axis come from day to month (bigger value scale).

I would like to ask: Can I make that functionality?

I am new with Core-Plot. So would you please show me how I can do
that, which method, class, delegate I should implement to make that
functionality.

Any help will be great appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but quite interesting.
I see two ways of dealing with it:

1. Using swipe gestures

   - Detect swipe gestures on the graph view;
   - When one is detected, start a fade out animation to hide the graph;
   - Update it (axis, plot space, reloadData, etc.) to display data in the unit that corresponds to the direction of the swipe gestures;
   - Fade in.
2. Using a UIScrollView

   - Create a UIScrollView with 3 pages (one fore each unit);
   - Display a different graph on each of these pages;
   - Implement navigation between the pages (eventually using a UIPageControl).